# Type error with Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Not sure what this means:

`Argument of type '{ tags: Tag[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Tag[]'.`

Offending lines:

`set_tags({tags}: Tag[]): void`

```
tags: Tag[] = [];
this.searchService.set_tags({ tags: this.tags });
```

The class:

```
export class Tag{
    select: string;
    search: string;
}
```

function works if I set `Tag[]` to `any` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
set_tags({tags}: Tag[]): void
```

This is the issue. `{tags}` here means an object which typescript type system finds incompatible with array type `Tag[]`.

As you mentioned  `set_tags({tags}: any): void` works and

```
set_tags(tags: Tag[]): void
```

should also work.
In which case you call

```
this.searchService.set_tags(this.tags );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because argument type declared in your `set_tags`  function is not matched when you call function with `this.searchService.set_tags({ tags: this.tags });`

Function Declaration should be as below :

```
set_tags(tags: Tag[]): void
```

and you need to call function like :

```
this.searchService.set_tags(this.tags);
```

Comment: trying the ES6 version of object passing, so then I don't have to remember the order to put them in.